# RabbitMQ Connector gives "TimeoutException: License topic could not be created"

Tags: apache-kafka, rabbitmq, apache-kafka-connect

My rabbitmq connector works fine when I run it in a server with no SASL. Actually it was working in a SASL activated server too but after restarting the Kafka Connect service now it won't start working. The error is:

```
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: License topic could not be created
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for a node assignment.
```

Is it a licensing issue? I don't think we purchased any license for it and it says there is a 30 days free trial. But also, I think we were using it for more than 30 days.

Edit: Found this in connect.log file:

```
INFO [AdminClient clientId=RabbitMQSinkConnector2-license-manager] Metadata update failed
```

Edit2: It has something to do with SASL. After enabling SASL for my broker, rabbitmq connector started giving this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by adding a little extra configuration for a sasl enabled broker, like I did for a debezium connector. You need to add these lines to your connector config:

```
"confluent.topic.sasl.mechanism": "PLAIN",
"confluent.topic.security.protocol": "SASL_PLAINTEXT",
"confluent.topic.sasl.jaas.config": "org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username=admin password=secret;"
```

If you don't want to expose your sasl credentials, you can save it in a file and change the last one like that:

```
"confluent.topic.sasl.jaas.config": "${file:/kafka/vty/pass.properties:sasl}"
```

But of course you need to enable reading from a file first.